# Get all open cases from salesforce API

Tags: api

For a dashboard I want to get some basic information about all cases. e.g get all open cases. I did find some api functionality to gather data by id about a single case.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/Case

Is is possible to receive data about all cases?

Comment: Retrieve Summary for Case option should give you all cases. Have you tried it?

Comment: Could you explain this? I'm not very familiar with salesforce but I am with api's

Comment: @Joroen This API gives you the Case records: `/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Case`
However what I observe is that not all fields are retrieved. I think you need to retrieve those records using Data Loader.

Comment: thanks! I'll have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to execute a SOQL query via [this API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm). Think of [SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) as a very basic version of SQL (some features not available, such as wildcards *), and the 'Case' object as your table. The query might look something like

```
SELECT Id, Subject, Status FROM Case WHERE IsClosed = false LIMIT 1000
```

And the request might look something like:

```
curl https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+Subject+Status+FROM+Case -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
```

Comment: Thanks, as soon as I have the credentials I'll let you know if it worked